# Using a common table expression with an OUTPUT clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

I see a huge performance gain using CTE v/s temporary table. Currently I have:

```
DECLARE @OutputTbl TABLE (ID INT)

INSERT INTO MyTable(Name, Address, PhoneNo)
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO @OutputTbl(ID)
VALUES ('Yatrix', '1234 Address Stuff', '1112223333')
```

I want to use a CTE here. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't use `INSERT` statement in the `CTE_query_definition`:

> Specifies a SELECT statement whose result set populates the common
> table expression. The SELECT statement for CTE_query_definition must
> meet the same requirements as for creating a view, except a CTE cannot
> define another CTE. For more information, see the Remarks section and
> CREATE VIEW (Transact-SQL).
>
> If more than one CTE_query_definition is
> defined, the query definitions must be joined by one of these set
> operators: UNION ALL, UNION, EXCEPT, or INTERSECT.

[CTE official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

[CREATE VIEW official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx)